# anaconda installation with python already installed

Tags: python, windows, installation, anaconda

I have python 3.8 installed in my windows 10 machine as system python.

I want to install anaconda. What precautions/steps should I take so that the system python does not interfere with the anaconda installation(which I am doing at a user level) while executing binaries or installing packages?

Comment: Read the docs: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no specific precautions to take: a standard install of Anaconda won't replace the default Python installation of your system, unless you ask for it explicitly during setup.

Afterwards, you will be able to create independent conda environments, each of them having their own Python version and set of packages.

As @Woodford pointed to in eir comment, you will learn a lot by looking at the docs.